# IOS: how to get called when press negative sign in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have customized cells for a tableview. So when negative sign on the left of cell is pressed in editing mode, I need to redraw my cell to make space for delete button.(Also need to recover after press negative sign again.) So I wonder if there is a method get called when negative sign is pressed, or is there other method to implement this. Thanks.

**Further update**

Thank you for your answer. But the first suggestion seems not work. The cell's setDditing:animated: is called when tableview is set editing, not negative sign clicked.
Could you explain more about the second suggestion? I used drawRect to show cell's view. Is it suitable for drawRect?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `setEditing:animated:` in your cell subclass. Make sure to also call the super implementation.

Alternatively, you can make sure that all of the elements in your cell have the correct autoresizing masks, and you may not have to write any custom code at all. Usually you set them to be a fixed distance from the left or right margin and to have a flexible width.